# Why does strerror_r behave differently when compiled with gnu90 and c90 standards?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, c89

Here is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
        char errbuf[256];

        errno = 0;
        strtoul("99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999", NULL, 0);
        strerror_r(errno, errbuf, sizeof errbuf);
        printf("strerror_r: %s\n", errbuf);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with `-std=gnu90` or `-std=gnu99`, I get the expected output.

```
susam@nifty:~/lab/linux$ rm -f a.out && gcc -std=gnu90 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic foo.c && ./a.out 
strerror_r: Numerical result out of range
susam@nifty:~/lab/linux$ rm -f a.out && gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic foo.c && ./a.out 
strerror_r: Numerical result out of range
```

But when I compile it with `-std=c90` or `-std=c99`, I get a warning and I don't see `strerror_r` putting the string in `errbuf`.

```
lone@debian:~/lab/linux$ rm -f a.out && gcc -std=c90 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic foo.c && ./a.out
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:12:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strerror_r’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  strerror_r(errno, errbuf, sizeof errbuf);
  ^
strerror_r:
lone@debian:~/lab/linux$ rm -f a.out && gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic foo.c && ./a.out
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:12:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strerror_r’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  strerror_r(errno, errbuf, sizeof errbuf);
  ^
strerror_r:
```

What is going wrong when I use `-std=c90` or `-std=c99`?

Comment: No definition of `strerror_r` was found in [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `-std=c89` you ask the implementation to provide exclusively the declarations for identifiers part of ISO 9899:1989. The identifier `strerror_r` is not part of C89 (or C99), so there is no prototype. In consequence you get the warning about an implicit declaration.

If you look at the relevant header you will likely find the strerror_r prototype buried in a maze of `#ifdef`s. The `-std` option changes the set of pre-defined macros affecting the visibility of the prototype.

Comment: But this does not explain why the output is different, does it?

Comment: Yes it does. Without a prototype, your implementation choses between one of two incompatible versions of strerror_r(). A comment in string.h explains: *There are 2 flavors of `strerror_r`, GNU which returns the string
   and may or may not use the supplied temporary buffer and POSIX one
   which fills the string into the buffer.
   To use the POSIX version, `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600` or `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L`
   without `-D_GNU_SOURCE` is needed, otherwise the GNU version is
   preferred.*

Comment: So, which version is used in the first case (gnu90/gnu99)? I assume the GNU version. In the second case therefore the posix version is used, which fills the string in the buffer. So, why isn't it printed?

Comment: If I interpret the macro maze correctly, gnu90/99 cause the XPG version to be used, i.e. *Fill BUF with a string describing the meaning of the `errno` code in ERRNUM.*. You can query the macros in effect by running `gcc -E -std=gnu90 -x c -dM string.h`.

Comment: Note that manpages for strerror_r() on many systems mistakenly claim that it is part of C99. It's not.

Answer (score 2):

**strerror_r**(3) says:

> The XSI-compliant strerror_r() is preferred for portable applications. It returns the error string in the user-supplied buffer buf of length buflen.
>
> The GNU-specific strerror_r() returns a pointer to a string containing the error message. This may be either a pointer to a string that the function stores in buf, or a pointer to some (immutable) static string (in which case buf is unused). If the function stores a string in buf, then at most buflen bytes are stored (the string may be truncated if buflen is too small and errnum is unknown). The string always includes a terminating null byte.

So it's not just a matter of whether the declaration is visible or not (which is a pretty big problem by itself - when you get an "Implicit declaration" warning, you shouldn't expect the program to work at all.) It's also a question of which version of the function you're calling. The GNU version sometimes returns a pointer to a constant string in the library instead of copying the string to the caller-supplied buffer.

The basic purpose of `strerror_r` isn't "I want the string in this buffer"; it's "I want a string that won't be overwritten by the library later."